# is there an equivalent of oracle sample clause in postgres

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

If I want a 'random' sample of rows from a table in an oracle database I can query

```
select * from mytable sample(1)
```

and get 1% back

Is there an equivalent command in Postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 9.5 or higher, you can use `TABLESAMPLE`:

```
TABLESAMPLE sampling_method ( argument [, ...] ) [ REPEATABLE ( seed ) ]
```

According to docs:

> A TABLESAMPLE clause after a table_name indicates that the specified
>   sampling_method should be used to retrieve a subset of the rows in
>   that table. This sampling precedes the application of any other
>   filters such as WHERE clauses. The standard PostgreSQL distribution
>   includes two sampling methods, BERNOULLI and SYSTEM, and other
>   sampling methods can be installed in the database via extensions.
>
> The BERNOULLI and SYSTEM sampling methods each accept a single
>   argument which is the fraction of the table to sample, expressed as a
>   percentage between 0 and 100. This argument can be any real-valued
>   expression. (Other sampling methods might accept more or different
>   arguments.) These two methods each return a randomly-chosen sample of
>   the table that will contain approximately the specified percentage of
>   the table's rows. The BERNOULLI method scans the whole table and
>   selects or ignores individual rows independently with the specified
>   probability. The SYSTEM method does block-level sampling with each
>   block having the specified chance of being selected; all rows in each
>   selected block are returned. The SYSTEM method is significantly faster
>   than the BERNOULLI method when small sampling percentages are
>   specified, but it may return a less-random sample of the table as a
>   result of clustering effects.
>
> The optional REPEATABLE clause specifies a seed number or expression
>   to use for generating random numbers within the sampling method. The
>   seed value can be any non-null floating-point value. Two queries that
>   specify the same seed and argument values will select the same sample
>   of the table, if the table has not been changed meanwhile. But
>   different seed values will usually produce different samples. If
>   REPEATABLE is not given then a new random sample is selected for each
>   query. Note that some add-on sampling methods do not accept
>   REPEATABLE, and will always produce new samples on each use.

Link: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html

Details from a blog introducing the feature: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/tablesample-in-postgresql-9-5-2/